# Why am I'm getting the error "Boolean needsPrivileges" when trying to install Xamarin for Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, privileges, error-log

> Iv noticed "Boolean needsPrivileges" coming up in the errors when
>   trying to install xamarin Part of the errors it gives every time i try
>   to install it say "Boolean needsPrivileges" so im not sure if I need
>   to some how give xamarin admin rights or something? Really i'm just
>   guessing for solutions though?
>
> here's the error log from Xamarin installer. Installation of 'Xamarin'
>   failed with more than one exception (attempt 3) Errors while
>   installing items. Exception type: System.AggregateException
>   Installation of archive
>   'C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.695.msi'
>   failed with exception. Exception type:
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException Full stack trace: at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String
>
> path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
>
> at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String
>   url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem
>   download) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
>   Installation of archive
>   'C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.695.msi'
>   failed with exception. Exception type:
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException Full stack trace: at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String
>
> path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
>
> at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String
>   url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem
>   download) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
>   Installation of archive
>   'C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.695.msi'
>   failed with exception. Exception type:
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException Full stack trace:
>
> at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String
>   path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
>
> at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String
>   url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem
>   download) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
>
> The installation log is way over the text limit but I noticed it also
>   says needsPrivileges ?I'm not sure how i give it the privileges it
>   needs there
>
> "[2016-10-08 12:08:05.637] [Exception] at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.InstallMSI(String file, Boolean
>   needsPrivileges, Action`3 processCommandArguments)"
>
> [2016-10-08 12:12:11.802] [Debug] Starting installation complete task.
>   [2016-10-08 12:12:11.809] [Info] Background installation worker
>   completed. [2016-10-08 12:12:11.917] [Info] Installation completed
>   with failure [2016-10-08 12:12:11.923] [Info] Status: failed.

Comment: This is simply a stack trace showing that certain methods have a parameter called `needsPrivileges`. You may want to just try giving the .msi "admin rights" via right clicking and `Run As Admin`. Otherwise please upload your full verbose IDE logs: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/#Xamarin_Universal_installer

Answer (score 0):

I also see this error and in my case I am using VS 2013.  Therefore I installed VS 2015 Build Tools, which can be found here:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\BuildTools_Full.exe
```

I then re-ran Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.695.msi from the downloads folder. Admin privileges are not necessary.